# Why the EventEmitter object does not emit the specified instance?

Tags: angular

I have these two components in Angular2, and a template for the `checklist` selector.

First, these are the two components:

```js
import {Component, EventEmitter} from '@angular/core';

export class ToDoItem{
    toDo: string;
    checked: boolean;

    constructor(toDo:string, checked: boolean){
        this.toDo = toDo;
        this.checked = checked;
    }
}

@Component({
    selector: 'to-do',
    inputs: ['toDoItem'],
    outputs: ['onToDoItemSelected'],
    styleUrls: ['./app.checklist.css'],
    template: `
        <input type="checkbox"><label class="strikethrough">{{toDoItem.toDo}}</label><button (click)="itemClicked()">Delete</button>
        `
})
export class ToDoItemComponent{
    toDoItem : ToDoItem;

    onToDoItemSelected: EventEmitter<ToDoItem>;

    constructor(){
        this.onToDoItemSelected = new EventEmitter();
    }

    itemClicked() : void {
        console.log(this.toDoItem);
        this.onToDoItemSelected.emit(this.toDoItem);
    }
}

@Component({
    selector: 'checklist',
    templateUrl: './app.checklist.html'
})
export class CheckList{
    toDoItems: Array<ToDoItem>;

    constructor(){
        this.toDoItems = [];
    }

    createToDo(description: string) : void {
        if (description !== ""){
            this.toDoItems.push(new ToDoItem(description, false));
        }
    }

    removeToDoItem(toDoItem: ToDoItem) : void {
        console.log(toDoItem);
        var indice = this.toDoItems.indexOf(toDoItem);
        this.toDoItems.splice(indice, 1);
    }
}
```

And this is the template file for the class `CheckList`:

```html
<h2>A Checklist</h2>
<span *ngIf="toDoItems.length == 0">
    There are not tasks yet...
</span>
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let toDoItem of toDoItems">
        <to-do [toDoItem]="toDoItem" (itemClicked)="removeToDoItem(toDoItem)"></to-do>
    </li>
</ul>

<hr>

<input type="text" placeholder="Enter the description..." #toDoDescription>
<button (click)="createToDo(toDoDescription.value); toDoDescription.value = '' ">Add</button>
```

Basically, the problem consists that it does not remove the item: the `EventEmitter` does not implicitly call `removeToDoItem`.

Some suggestions, ideas,.. to solve it?

Comment: What value does `indice` have after the 3rd line in `removeToDoItem(...)`?

Comment: `this.toDoItems.splice(indice, 1);` removes the given item from the array `toDoItems`. The `console.log` does not print anything.

Comment: This example works as expected http://pastebin.com/91Dd54mL. I've used it as model to define the code in the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

your import file is wrong. For doing this you should use EventEmitter like this.

```js
import { Component, EventEmitter, Input, Output } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'rio-counter',
    templateUrl: 'app/counter.component.html'
})
export class CounterComponent {
    @Input()  count = 0;
    @Output() result = new EventEmitter<number>();

    increment() {
        this.count++;
        this.result.emit(this.count);
    }
}
```

child class html

```html
<div>
    <p>Count: {{ count }}</p>
    <button (click)="increment()">Increment</button>
</div>
```

parent component should be like this.

```js
import { Component, OnChanges } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'rio-app',
    templateUrl: 'app/app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent implements OnChanges {
    num = 0;
    parentCount = 0;

    ngOnChanges(val: number) {
    this.parentCount = val;
  }
}
```

parent html part

```html
<div>
    Parent Num: {{ num }}<br />
    Parent Count: {{ parentCount }}
    <rio-counter [count]="num" (result)="ngOnChanges($event)">
    </rio-counter>
</div>
```

example for reference taken from rangle.io notes. now use @Output() onToDoItemSelected and import Output  and in parent component call (onToDoItemSelected)="removeToDoItem($event)". i hope this will help

Comment: I have made the changes you have suggested, but `OnChange` does not belong to `angular/core`: https://www.dropbox.com/s/9t1yq7hqcb7wnql/Ejercicio-2-OnChange.png?dl=0

Comment: @infZero i think you are using old angular angular/core package. can you show your package.json file. actually onChange belongs to angular/core. here is offical angular link https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#parent-to-child-on-changes

Comment: `package.json`: https://www.dropbox.com/s/p00t31vkb67p4kk/package.json?dl=0

Comment: and you don't need to call ngOnChange function you should use (onToDoItemSelected)="removeToDoItem($event)" . i have used just to show you how to emit a event.

Comment: plz use OnChanges not OnChange i have update it also. sorry for that. i used it for reference from rangle.io they have used Onchange.. your package.json file is fine.

Comment: @infZero let me know if you face any issue.

Comment: I have made this example http://pastebin.com/91Dd54mL and it works using this `outputs: ['putRingOnIt']` specification in the `Component` annotation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130894/discussion-between-amit-suhag-and-infzero).

Answer (score 0):

I believe that's because you're not providing the right argument to `removeToDoItem`. In your `CheckList` template you have:

```
(itemClicked)="removeToDoItem(toDoItem)"
```

With an `EventEmitter` the argument you `emit` is actually the `$event` data, like it would be with a `(click)`. So your code should be:

```
(itemClicked)="removeToDoItem($event)"
```

That should pass the correct data to the `removeToDoItem` of `CheckList` without any other changes.

Answer (score 0):

There is no event or `@Output() itemClicked`, therefore `(itemClicked)="removeToDoItem(toDoItem)"` doesn't cause `removeToDoItem()` to be called.

Perhaps you meant

```
(click)="itemClicked(toDoItem)
```

Comment: I have specified `outputs: ['onToDoItemSelected']` in the declaration of `ToDoItemComponent`.

Comment: I can't see much resemblance between your code and the pastebin.